# Changes /edits not reflected on live site but can publish new or delete

Tags: channel-entries

I have a site I moved from one server to another and everything looks good but when I try and edit an entry the changes are accepted and saved, but when I view the front/public page the changes/edits are not being shown.

If I go back and look at the entry, the changes are still saved, just not on the front end.

This is an EE 1.7.3 site

I checked my config file and the database settings are correct.  How could the changes be saved on the back end but not the front end?

Strangely I can add a new entry or delete an entry, just not make an edit

Comment: What happens if you modify the URL in a way that would return the same page but break the cache? (add a query string at the end or something)

Answer (score 1):

If you moved the site from one server to another (the actual physical files) then did you delete the Cache folder or not?

Have you tried to delete it and see if that fixes things on the front end?

As to the backend you say you can't edit some entries but in what way **can't** you edit the entries? Can you click on them to edit them but then they don't save or do you click on the save button and you get an error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any template or entry caching going on?  Or third party caching at the server level? Can you verify that what's showing on the front end is in fact the entry you think it is by exposing but commenting out the entry id in the template?

Comment: no template caching or caching at the server. Yes I can verify that these are in fact the entries.  Bizarre I can publish something new and the entry looks fine, but I cannot edit an entry.

Even if I close an entry it still shows on the page.  Another note is I can edit any new entries.  I just cannot edit any OLD entries from before the change over to the new server.

Comment: Can you answer the last template portion of Jean's question?

Comment: I am not sure I follow: exposing but commenting out the entry id

Comment: I can confirm I am looking at the correct entry id on the front end and back end and the content that was updated in the entry are not the same.

Comment: How do I check if the templates are being cached?  I have found if I create a new template by duplicating on old one the changes seem to be live.

Comment: Strange that 2 templates with the exact same code work differently.  I have cleared all the cache data under admin > Utilities > Clear Cache Data and the template cache is set to NO

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a strange caching issue.  I was forced to duplicate the template group and everything works as it should.